# Mobile App Event not triggering Journey

Tags: journeybuilder, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android

We have enabled mobile app events in our salesforce instance.
We have followed all the required procedures to setup the events, creating and uploading a csv file, etc as shown below. Then we created a journey that is triggered by the event mentioned above.

[image]

[image]

In order to trigger the journey we send an event via the iOS or Android mobile applications we have, that communicate with our salesforce instance.

[image]

However, the journey is not triggered at all. Any ideas?

Edit: Added an error found in salesforce after talking with support

```
    2022-01-13 20:06:26.930, ErrorID="10683498000", ErrorCodeID="21179", ClientID="510002421", UserID="710243775", EnterpriseID="510002421", ErrorDate="2022-01-13 14:06:26.93", DeveloperDesc="Unable to process event. {
"applicationId": "c4e39c0b-d3a3-4243-afe3-b8f8ce15e757",
"deviceId": "ad27027c-ee42-4655-9fff-41bb4a499d34",
"eventDateUTC": "2022-01-13T20:06:16.8Z",
"name": "Viewed Screen",
"attributes": {
"Screen Name": "TES2T"
},
"metaData": {
"deviceID": "ad27027c-ee42-4655-9fff-41bb4a499d34",
"etAppId": "c4e39c0b-d3a3-4243-afe3-b8f8ce15e757",
"hwid": "Google Pixel 4",
"platform": "Android",
"platform_Version": "12",
"sdk_Version": "8.0.1",
"app_Version": "1.1 : 2",
"locale": "en_US",
"dST": false,
"timeZone": 7200,
"location_Enabled": false,
"backgroundRefreshEnabled": true,
"push_Enabled": true,
"identity": {
"platform": "Android",
"registrationId": "ad27027c-ee42-4655-9fff-41bb4a499d34",
"PUSH": {
"profileId": "viccc",
"applicationId": "c4e39c0b-d3a3-4243-afe3-b8f8ce15e757",
"attributes": {}
}
}
}
}", ExceptionDetail="ExactTarget.Core.BaseETException: Unable to process event. {
"applicationId": "c4e39c0b-d3a3-4243-afe3-b8f8ce15e757",
"deviceId": "ad27027c-ee42-4655-9fff-41bb4a499d34",
"eventDateUTC": "2022-01-13T20:06:16.8Z",
"name": "Viewed Screen",
"attributes": {
"Screen Name": "TES2T"
},
"metaData": {
"deviceID": "ad27027c-ee42-4655-9fff-41bb4a499d34",
"etAppId": "c4e39c0b-d3a3-4243-afe3-b8f8ce15e757",
"hwid": "Google Pixel 4",
"platform": "Android",
"platform_Version": "12",
"sdk_Version": "8.0.1",
"app_Version": "1.1 : 2",
"locale": "en_US",
"dST": false,
"timeZone": 7200,
"location_Enabled": false,
"backgroundRefreshEnabled": true,
"push_Enabled": true,
"identity": {
"platform": "Android",
"registrationId": "ad27027c-ee42-4655-9fff-41bb4a499d34",
"PUSH": {
"profileId": "viccc",
"applicationId": "c4e39c0b-d3a3-4243-afe3-b8f8ce15e757",
"attributes": {}
}
}
}
}
---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Line 23, position 18
```

.

Thanks in advance,
V.

Comment: Please open a support case and have the support engineer at-mention me.

Comment: Hello @BillMote We have already opened a ticket and we propesed to open a stackechange ticket. I edited the post with the error message that a support agent found.

Comment: Support should _never_ be sending you here.  :(

Comment: Please have them at-mention me on the support case.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the response!